# How I run the following Ns3 project form GitHub

Tags: github, ns-3

I need to where put folers ,files in ns3 of the following project from github step by step to run it.

https://github.com/gdbranco/RA5G_NS3

Comment: I suggest you reach out to the authors. Else, I would build NS-3 from the official doc and add the module you are interested on from [the /src dir](https://github.com/gdbranco/RA5G_NS3/tree/master/src)

Answer (score 1):

This is a fork of my fork. You need CMake to configure it and build (waf probably won't work correctly as this was very early on CMake support development and I've changed a ton of files).
Instructions are available here: https://gabrielcarvfer.github.io/NS3/installation

Not sure what you want from it specifically, but feel free to reach out to Guilherme. He's awesome.

Comment: I dont know where to put folders in the link @Gabriel

Comment: You need to be more specific. What folders? The project folder? You can clone it wherever you want.

Comment: I need the way after download it . what i do @Gabriel

Comment: Open the folder with CLion and it will configure the CMake project. Or create a cmake_cache folder, then navigate to it (cd cmake_cache) and call cmake to configure the project (e.g. cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=relwithdebinfo .. && make -j8). Output binaries and libraries will be in RA5G_NS3/build/bin and RA5G_NS3/build/lib.